# In an electron diffraction experiment, why must the diaphragm be considered as a quantum object?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

In the book *Quantum Mechanics*, Volume 1, written by Albert Messiah, page no. 142-143, the author says:

> but the diaphragm is a quantum object, just like the electron. Its momentum is not defined to better than $dp$

I do not understand why diaphragm is a quantum object.

Also, it is not clear to me what author says below:

> One must postulate that the measuring apparatus is a quantized object which also obeys uncertainty relations

On the other hand, N. Bohr says that the measuring apparatus is always a classical object (i.e. an instrument which follows the rules of classical mechanics).

Any *clear* explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Quantum mechanics does apply to the measuring apparatus. There is a large literature on this starting with Hugh Everett's 1957 paper on relative states:

http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.29.454.

After the measurement, the apparatus exists in multiple versions that don't interfere, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033.

The reason they don't interfere is that the information required to produce interference spreads into the environment, this is commonly called decoherence:

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072

http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245.

Some of this literature fudges the issue of whether other versions of the apparatus exist after measurement, but this is not a viable position since the EPR correlations are a result of quantum information being carried in decoherent systems:

arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223.

Comment: (1) Decoherence is not full-proof theory. It is impossible to test correctness of decoherence since you simply can not observe so-called interference of "quantum states" of a "classical object"! This is my view. Your explanation does not answer my question.
(2) When Albert Messiah was writing this book, concept of decoherence did not exist to my knowledge. I am asking what is that which compelled Albert Messiah to write this statement: diaphragm is a quantum object.
(3) You did not consider N. Bohr's axiom: Quantum results MUST be expressed in classical language.

Comment: It's historically silly that the application  of QM to the apparatuses started with Everett in the 1950s. Already the Bohr-Einstein debates in the 1920s were full of these things, $dp$ of the apparatuses and their parts etc., and they were doing quite complicated things with those things. And Bohr did these things correctly, unlike Einstein.

Comment: Bohr assumed, wrongly, that measurements must be described in classical terms. Everett didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Messiah's assertion is based simply on the fact that the diaphragm is a physical object. If you accept that all physical objects follow quantum mechanics, then it follows that the diaphragm is also a quantum object.

Of course, if you postulate that all physical objects follow quantum mechanics, then a number of other problems appear, like the fact that we do not in everyday life observe cats which are |dead⟩+|alive⟩. Let me be clear and upfront: there is as yet **no** accepted way to solve this problem. This is the fundamental open problem in the foundations of quantum mechanics, and it is usually known as the *measurement problem*. A good starting point for reading about it is [the Wikipedia page on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem) *and* the references at its bottom. For a good exposition of what the problem actually is, I really like [this lecture by Rob Spekkens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT2We5i5N6o).

There are a number of ways to try and grapple with this problem, which include such weird-looking constructions as Bohmian mechanics, the many-worlds formalism, and decoherence calculations.

In particular, Bohr's prescriptions - drawing a strict line between classical and quantum mechanics - are a way of handling this. They have proved quite successful in understanding experiments, but they are not devoid of problems and you should **not** treat them as undisputed truth. In particular, there is as yet no consistent, clear criterion about where to place this quantum-to-classical barrier.

Comment: Finally, I must note that if you 'don't want to read' literature on the subject, and you're not willing to question the validity of assumptions - including Bohr's prescriptions - then there are fairly strict limits on how well you will understand the subject.